# Is there a way to Archive files and folders to a specific folder in Google Drive and keep folder path?

Tags: google-apps-script, flysystem-google-drive

I'm using Google Drive and I'd like to Archive all the files synced with my computer which are older than a certain amount of time.
As a result, the archived files will disappear from my computer on the next sync.

I've found several scripts to perform the file moving but it seems challenging to move the file and keep the path structure as if it was moved using a robocopy/powershell command locally on the computer.

any idea if such feature is possible with Google Apps Scripts?

So far, I haven't integrated yet the copy/remove function. I'm retrieving the folder path and I guess there must be a way to check if path already exists in destination and if not, create subfolders?

```
function FilesModifiedLastWeek(){

// Find files modified last week

  var today     = new Date();
  var oneDayAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);  
  var startTime = oneDayAgo.toISOString();

  // The magic search expression
  var search = '(trashed = true or trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > "' + startTime + '")';
  var files  = DriveApp.searchFiles(search);

  // Loop through all the files in the search results
  while( files.hasNext() ) {

    var file = files.next();

    var fileName    = file.getName();
    var parentFolder = file.getParents();
    folders = [];

    //Get full path
    while (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
      parentFolder = parentFolder.next();
      var title = parentFolder.getName();
      folders.push(parentFolder.getName());
      parentFolder = parentFolder.getParents();
    }
    var fileURL     = file.getUrl();
    var dateCreated =  Utilities.formatDate(file.getDateCreated(), "Europe/Zurich", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    Logger.log("Filename: " + fileName + " Folder path: " + folders.reverse().join("/") + " File creation date:" + dateCreated);
  }
}
```

Additional point, is it a way to exclude the Archive folder from the search? :)

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "keep the folder path"? Where is it supposed to be kept?

Comment: Hi, what I mean is, if the file to be moved if located under My Compter/LambdaFolder/AlphaSubFolder/Myfile.pdf, I'd like to store this file under Archive/LambdaFolder/AlphaSubFolder/Myfile.pdf

Comment: The getFoldersByName(name) method can be called on the instance of the Folder class to get all child folders. If the FolderIterator returned by this method returns true after calling hasNext(),  the folder already exists, if not - it must be created (that also means the whole path doesn't exist). You can repeat this process for the entire path and then move the file to the last folder and remove it from the previous parent. This will allow you to move the file without copying it. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the [Advanced Drive Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) and one extra function in your code.

We will be using the [Patch command](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) to add and remove parent folders.

> Optional query parameters
>
> **addParents**    *string*    A comma-separated list of parent IDs to add.
>
> **removeParents** *string*    A comma-separated list of parent IDs to remove.

The code is like this:

```
function placeFileInFolders(file, folders) {
  var archiveFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Archive Folder").next();
  
  var lastFolder = archiveFolder;
  for (var i=0; i<folders.length; i++) {
    if (lastFolder.getFoldersByName(folders[i]).hasNext()) {
      lastFolder = lastFolder.getFoldersByName(folders[i]).next();
    } else {
      lastFolder = lastFolder.createFolder(folders[i]);
    }
  }
  var newFile = Drive.Files.patch({}, file.getId(), {
    addParents: lastFolder.getId(),
    removeParents: file.getParents().next().getId()
  });
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
    //...
    Logger.log("Filename: " + fileName + " Folder path: " + folders.reverse().join("/") + " File creation date:" + dateCreated);
    placeFileInFolders(file, folders.reverse());
    //...
```

## Improvements

### Shared with Me

I've also added one extra case where your code will be able to handle files "Shared With Me".

```
    //...
    if (!parentFolder.hasNext()) {
      folders.push("Shared With Me");
    }
    while (parentFolder.hasNext()) {
    //...
```

### Delete empty folders

This script does not remove folders that have all their contents moved to the Archive.

Comment: Had to change :
//...
placeFileInFolders(file, folders);
...//
Otherwise, works like a charm!
2 points: - Any chance to exclude Archive Folder in the initial search? - Empty folders aren't deleted as you mentioned. Would it be difficult to add this feature, taking into account the whole path?
Good thought for Shared with me! :)

Comment: @poypoy you can use [custom properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties) and then exclude them on your search query with "and (not(properties has 'archived')".
To delete empty folders you will have to, after moving a file, check if the previous parent folder is empty.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I've tried the not properties setting and I'm getting a q error on files.HasNext(). I guess there are some quotes not setup properly in the search property. Is it the right way to use this? 
var search = '(trashed = true or trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > "' + startTime + '") and (not(properties has "archived"))';

Comment: When you want to use quotes inside of a string, remember to escape them. This means, turn " into \". This needs to be done only for the internal quotes. `var search = "(trashed = true or trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > \"" + startTime + "\") and (not(properties has \"archived\"))";`

Comment: thanks for the insight. However, the same error remains. I've modified the query as such and now, it does what I was looking for :)
`var search = "(trashed = true or trashed = false) and (modifiedDate > \"" + startTime + "\") and (not \"root\" in parents)";`
Cheers